# Delphi - Memo Right Click Get Line Number

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, tmemo

How do I get the line number of a memo when I right click on it?

A ListBox has .ItemAtPos but I've not been able to find a similar function

-Brad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi 2010, TRichEdit has an ActiveLineNo property.  Not sure if it exists in Delphi 2009.

The manual way to get the line number is to send the Memo an EM_LINEFROMCHAR message with the WParam value set to -1, ie:

```
LineNo := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, -1, 0);
```

Or:

```
LineNo := Memo1.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, -1, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check CaretPos property.

Comment: That answer works perfectly, and is simple to use:
  Y := MatchMemo.CaretPos.Y;
  s := MatchMemo.Lines[Y];